# How can I send data between a link to the tab it opens in Modern UI Link page WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, modern-ui

I am doing a project in WPF and I am using the 3rd Party library Modern UI or Mui.

I am using the library's Modern List page to present the user a bunch of dynamically found IP addresses. As a result I want that for each new IP link on the left, there will be a page about it on the right. The problem is that because the IP addresses are dynamically found, I need to dynamically create the pages as well. (Example in the picture below)

So I want to send the data to the page when it is being clicked so I will be able to create a distinct page, or set the source of the link to a dynamically created page.

This is the library: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui

I have searched for a long time with no solution, any information/help ?

[[Picture] I want each link to show a different page without creating them beforehand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydlln.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using ModernUI for a while. Just wanted to know, is there a specific requirement because of which you are trying to use the list window?

I assume you are using a layout like the settings page in the ModernUI template.

It would be easier to use a UserControl with an items control on the left and a content control on the right with a template selector in a way that the selected item type changes the content UI and selected item of same type changes the layout and data. Let me know if you need suggestions on this. I had a requirement where I implemented this in a similar way in ModernUI.

As the pages displayed within are user controls, you can easily place them in the content control as well.

Comment: Do not create pages. Just a single page and change the DataContext of the   Right Page to the selected item. As soon as you change the data context, binding will update the UI for the selected item immediately.